# Compute the expected value of median of rolling a die three times.

Tags: probability, expected-value, median

The following is an interview question.

> Question: Compute the expected value of median of rolling a die three times.

I solved the question in the following manner:

Let $X$ be the median. Then, for any $1\leq x\leq 6,$ $x$ is a median consists of three possible scanarios: all three dice give $x$, or two dice give $x$ and another dice gives anything or all three dice give different numbers and one of them gives $x$.

By using reasoning above, we have 
$$P(X=x) = \frac{1}{216} + \binom{3}{1} \frac{5}{216} + \frac{3! (x-1)(6-x)}{216} = \frac{-3x^2+21x-10}{108}.$$
Therefore, 
$$E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^6 xP(X=x) = \sum_{x=1}^6 x\frac{-3x^2+21x-10}{108} = 3.5$$
from [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bx%3D1%7D%5E6%20x%2F108%5B-3x%5E2%20%2B%2021x%20-%2010%5D) .

What interests me is that the final answer is the same as expected value of a single die.

I am wondering whether there is a shorter way to solve the problem.

Comment: Symmetry: the outcome $(x,y,z)$ has the same probability as $(7-x,7-y,7-z)$ and the median of the first configuration plus the median of the second one is always $7$.

Comment: @fedja Perhaps you can elaborate more and put it as an answer?

Comment: I think you're confused about the definition of "median."  Please re-read the definitions.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Isn't median the second number in sorted sequence of $X_1, X_2, X_3$?

Comment: Yes... in the case of three samples.  But for two samples it is mid-way between the two values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already noted in a comment, the result can be derived from symmetry without any calculation. The probability distribution of the die is invariant under the symmetry transformation $x\to7-x$, a reflection about $x=\frac72$. Thus the median and the mean must also be invariant under this transformation. Thus they must be the centre of the reflection, $x=\frac72$.

Comment: After I read your answer again. I have a doubt. What do you mean by 'invariant under the symmetry transformation $x\mapsto 7-x$? Is there a definition?

Comment: @Idonknow: It means: All probabliities are exactly the same in the actual situation and in the situation where all values are transformed according to $x\to7-x$. E.g. the sequence $2,4,3$ of rolls has the same probability as the sequence $5,3,4$. Of course there's in fact much more symmetry than that; the probabilities are invariant under all permutations of the face values; but because this is a linear transformation, the mean and the median must also be invariant under it if the probabilities are.