# Expectation value of the median of five dice roll

Tags: probability, expected-value

The question goes as:

1. First of all, imagine you roll a dice five times, what is the expected median of the roll?

(the answer should be 7/2 which is exactly the same as a single roll. Found people on the internet are talking about symmetry argument, but I don't quite understand why that works)

2. Again, we roll a dice five times, calculate the expected value of the square of medium value.

Comment: The first part of your question is addressed in [Compute the expected value of median of rolling a die three times.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3504717/139123) Next time please just ask one question.

Comment: For the first part, I think I got it! For the second part, I don't think the previous thread provides a detailed explanation about how to approach it. Still need some help.....

Comment: Oh. I think I got it! Thanks guys!